# Any proofs of $[f(X)]^c = f(X^c)$?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

In a proof on continuity, the author heavily relies on the fact that $[f(X)]^c = f(X^c)$ to make a statement about continuity.  In words, this states that the complement of the image is equal to the image of the complement. Are there any proofs out there on this? I haven't seen any. I have an idea for how we could prove this. (Although, I will point out that my proof isn't a general result; it heavily relies on having both the domain and domain be the universal set. I understand and acknowledge this in advance.)

---

**Proof Idea**

Suppose $X$ is a subset of a space $\mathbb{X}$ and let $f:\mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{X}$ be a continuous function.

Then $f(X) \subset \mathbb{X}.$ Now consider $X^c$. Obviously, $X \cup X^c = \mathbb{X}$. Then $f(X)\cup f(X^c)=f(X\cup X^c)=f(\mathbb{X})=\mathbb{X}$.

Since $f(X)\cup f(X^c)= \mathbb{X}, \hspace{0.5cm}f(X^c)= \mathbb{X} \setminus f(X)$

But notice that $\mathbb{X} \setminus f(X) = [f(X)]^c$. This is *only* the case because we already established that $\mathbb{X}$ can be expressed as the union of $f(X)$ and $f(X^c)$.

Thus, we have shown that $[f(X)]^c = f(X^c) \hspace{1cm} \square$

---

What do you think of my idea for the proof? Does it work? Let me know what you think. I just haven't seen any formal proofs of this lemma.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Take $X=\mathbb{X}=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x)=x^2$. Then $[f(X)]^c=(-\infty,0)$ but $f(X^c)=\emptyset$

Comment: You have two steps that aren't valid without more assumptions: $$f(\mathbb{X}) = \mathbb{X}$$ and $$f(X) \cup f(X^c) = \mathbb{X} \implies f(X^c) = \mathbb{X} \setminus f(X)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any function $f:A \to B$, if $f(A \setminus S)=B \setminus f(S)$ for all subsets $S$ of $A$, then $f$ must necessarily be a bijection.

Injectivity: If $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ but $a_1 \ne a_2$, then let $S=A \setminus \{a_1\}$. Then, $f(A \setminus S)=\{f(a_1)\}$, but $f(a_1) \notin B \setminus f(S)$, so $f(A \setminus S) \ne B \setminus f(S)$. This contradicts the assumption that $f(A \setminus S)=B \setminus f(S)$, so $f$ must be injective.

Surjectivity: Let $S=\emptyset$. Then, $f(A)=f(A \setminus \emptyset)=B \setminus f(\emptyset)=B \setminus \emptyset=B$, so $f$ must also be surjective.

So, the statement is true only for continuous bijections $\mathbb{X} \to \mathbb{X}$ (which need not, in general, be homeomorphisms).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to prove something that isn't true.

Take $f : \emptyset \to \{0\}$. Then $f(\emptyset^c) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, but $(f(\emptyset))^c = \emptyset^c = \{0\}$.